# Is this quotient group isomorphic to something?

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I was solving some basic exercises on simplicial homology and
found Ker$\partial_{1}$ is generated by $n+1$ edges $\{a_{0},a_{1},...,a_{n}\}$, and Im$\partial_{2}$ generated by $\{a_{0},2a_{1}-a_{0},2a_{2}-a_{1},...,2a_{n}-a_{n-1}\}$. Should I say Ker$\partial_{1}/$Im$\partial_{2}$ is isomorphic to something? I only know basic group theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Think of the elements $a_i$ in the kernel as being generators of a free abelian group on $n+1$ elements, and the generators of the image as being the relations that the $a_i$ satisfy in the quotient.

So the fact that $a_0$ is in the image says that $a_0 = 0$ in the quotient, 
so we don't need to include $a_0$ among the generators of the quotient.

Now the next relation says that $2a_1 = a_0 = 0$ in the quotient, so $a_1$ is an element of order $2$ in the quotient.

The next relation says that $2 a_2 = a_1$ in the quotient, so actually,
we don't need to include $a_1$ as a generator of the quotient --- it is already in the subgroup gen'd by $a_2$, and we see that $4a_2 = 0$, 
so $a_2$ has order $4$.

Can you continue?